# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Parameters of time-varying Normal distribution

Tags: python, minimize

I want to using Maximum Likelihood method to estimate  Parameters of time-varying Normal distribution.in my study,normal distribution has two parameters, in which the location parameter changes with time and the scale parameter is a constant. My code is as follows:

```
def MLE_Norm(parameters):
  
   beta_0, beta_1, sigma = parameters
   t=np.arange(1,62)
   loc = beta_0 + beta_1*t
   LL = np.sum(stats.norm.logpdf(one_tm, loc=loc, scale=sigma))
   neg_LL = -1*LL
   return neg_LL 

mle_model = minimize(MLE_Norm, np.array([1000,1000,500]), method='L-BFGS-B')
mle_model
```

give the result as follows

[image]

May I ask everyone, what went wrong and why message: 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'.
Thank you so much!

I really don't know how to use the maximum likelihood method to estimate the time-varying Normal distribution, and there is no corresponding code instance from Google.So I would like to consult everyone.Thanks!